# How to allow less secure app access in Microsoft email?

Tags: email, security, hotmail

I am looking to manage my email from a third party application and would like to connect it to my email account.

For my google, I was able to go in my security setting to allow less secure app access and now my application is able to access it.

Similarly, for yahoo mail, I went into security and there is a way to generate an application-specific password to bypass strong security measures.

Now my only issue is my Hotmail account. I can't find an option to allow less secure applications like in the other two mail services. I am quite sure it is hidden somewhere. Can anyone here help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

if you are using outlook email so go to your mail account,
or type this link In your browser ▶,https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/options/mail/accounts/popImap
Then Click on ▶ Sync email, then goto ▶(POP and IMAP) section, and
click on ▶YES, to ▶Let devices and apps use POP.
in last save it.

enjoy.